# Google sheets percentage of values where the difference between two columns in another sheet, is less than the value in a third column of the sheet

Tags: google-sheets, count, countif

I'm on google sheets trying to find the percentage of values where the difference between two columns in another sheet, is less than the value in a third column of the sheet. I've tried a bunch of things but all come up with err0rs or parse error. Any help is appreciated.

This is what I came up with.

=COUNTIF((sum(Data!($E$2:$E$229):Data!($F$2:$F$229)),"<Data!$C$2:$C$229"))/count(Data!$C$2:$C$229)

then I make it a percentage value
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. So we don't know your layout, data, data types, data scope, range inclusions, etc. We also don't know what the desired results are, only that what you are doing isn't working. Consider sharing a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it) where you have *hand-entered* at least a few rows of the output you expect to see, where you'd like a formula to produce those results. In your post, be clear about where the volunteer contributors here should look for those results.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, the simplest strategy would probably be something like this:

In the sheet with the two columns, calculate another column that is the difference of the first two. E.g.:
`=A1-B1`.

Then, write an if statement that checks whether that difference is less than the value in the third column. If it is, return 1, if it isn't return 0. E.g.:
`=IF(C1<D1, 1, 0)`

Finally, calculate the percentage of values that are less with a formula like this:
`=SUM(if_column) / COUNTA(if_column) * 100`

SUM returns the count of all cells whose difference is less than the third column and COUNTA returns the total number of non-blank cells.